# Ubuntu 12.04 Unity starts in 2D mode even when 3D is selected - ATI Radeon HD 4250 Legacy Driver 13.1

Tags: 12.04, unity, drivers, ati

After installing the ATI Radeon legacy drivers (version 13.1) Unity no longer starts in 3D mode, where it did before. I can select "Ubuntu" during login, and indeed it is the default choice, but when I do login Unity loads 2D mode instead of 3D mode. I cannot get Unity to start in 3D at all, even after running unity --reset.

The output of lscpi | grep VGA is as follows:

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880M     [Mobility Radeon HD 4225/4250]
```

I tried some of the solutions in the post Damien mentioned below, including reverting back to open source drivers. No luck, as

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

returns "Not software rendered" as "no". But unity 3d had always worked until just the other day. So how do I get it to software render?

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/q/134097/71679

Comment: I tried some of the solutions in that post, including reverting back to open source drivers. No luck /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p 
returns "Not software rendered" as "no". But unity 3d had always worked until just the other day. Odd.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` was set to "nomodeset". I changed it to "quiet splash", which is the default. Then I ran `sudo update-grub` and rebooted.